# How can I access the locational data of the currently selected file or folder?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, execute-command

I want to be able to select a file, run a script with a shortcut and that script gets the path of the file I've selected (or am dragging). I've selected it in nautilus.

I know how to run the command, I just don't know how to get the location of the selected file. I am assuming it is possible, because if I drag and drop a file to terminal, it pastes the path...

---

What did I use this for? I have a program called [synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) which is for using 1 mouse and 1 keyboard across many computers, using a local network.

You can set it up to have your screens next to each other like so:

[image]

However, (because this is the free version), I can't drag and drop files between them. So this dock is set up between the two screens, and when I drag a file I can drop it there - and it copies it to the same path on the second computer (if it exists) or to the misc folder.

Comment: It would be informative if you could mention how to run command at the edge.

Comment: @daltonfury42 the what?

Comment: @daltonfury42 yes, GNOME 3

Comment: @daltonfury42 with the commands section of `ccsm`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to _what_ you are trying to drag a file/icon/whatever from?

Comment: @codingman a file or folder... and from nautilus.

Comment: @Tim doesn't nautilus show the path at the top?

Comment: @codingman yes it does. Can you read the question again? I'm dragging a file. Then I run a command with a shortcut. How can that command get the path of the file I'm dragging?

Comment: @Tim Could you please elaborate on what application you are trying to get that file path into?

Comment: @codingman I'm clicking and dragging a file. I then run a command with a keyboard shortuct. I wish for that script to access the path of the file I'm dragging - as a variable.

Comment: Is it OK if the path is provided by dropping the file on desktop icon?

Comment: @VRR not really... it could be a window pops up below where the mouse is.

Comment: I can't understand why you would want to do this, but glad it got fixed for you...

Comment: It would be really interesting to know what you did with it. Can you please add it in the question?

Comment: @daltonfury42 will do tomorrow, it's getting late for me now :)

Comment: @daltonfury42 I've edited to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little reaserch, I found out what you may be looking for. This can be done using `.desktop` files. Let me demonstrate.

Create a file in your home diretory(as an example) with the extension `.desktop` with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=bash <path-to-your-script> %u
Name=visible name here
Comment=comment here
Icon=icon path here
```

Replace `<path-to-your-script>` with path of the script you want to execute. Here `%u` is the path of the file which you will be dragging on the .desktop file to trigger the script. This will obviously be passed as an argument to your script.

Don't forget to make your `.desktop`  executable as well by:

```
chmod u+x test.desktop
```

To check if it is working you can point it to this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $1 > ~/out.txt
```

You will see the full path of the file which you dragged onto your .desktop file stored in out.txt in you home directory.

Finally, you can set up a dock to have just this in it, so you have it at the side of the screen.

References:

[Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html)

[Gnome Developer - Desktop Files](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en)

Comment: Yeah, this works with Plank dock, I can have *just* that icon on it - and it can be where I want.

Comment: @Tim, good to hear.

Comment: I'll add the bounty in 4 hours

Answer (score 2):

For those who didn't liked the dock solution can simply make use of Nautilus environment variable `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` or `$@`.Write a script, place it in the *scripts folder* so it will appear in context menu. The advantage is that you can select more files at once. To test it:

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
exit 0
```